# Call odoo controller through Postman

Tags: postman, odoo

I'm getting stuck when trying to test a router by calling from Postman

```
    @http.route('/nails/login', type='json', auth="public")
    def api_login(self, csrf=False, **kwargs):
```

and calling in postman with header application/json

```
http://127.0.0.1:8070/nails/login
```

but log always return

```
2018-07-02 14:30:38,123 26497 ERROR ? odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/ryu/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
     return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
   File "/home/ryu/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1453, in _dispatch_nodb
    func, arguments = self.nodb_routing_map.bind_to_environ(request.httprequest.environ).match()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1573, in match
     raise NotFound()
NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
2018-07-02 14:30:38,128 26497 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2018 14:30:38] "POST /nails/login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 8):

Before calling any API, you have to login using `/web/session/authenticate` using post request. The reason for the above error is odoo is not able to find session information, therefore unable to find which database to login.
Sample request type:

```json
{
  "params": {
    "login": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "db": "odoo10"
  }
}
```

Comment: But his route has an `auth` of `public`, which according to the [docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/http.html#routing) means that authentication shouldn't be necessary to hit the endpoint...

Comment: When multiple odoo databases with same version exists, this problem arises

Answer (score 3):

Finally I resolved it by adding this in configuration file, ever try but not sure why it's not working before that..

```
[options]
dbfilter = my_db_name
```

Comment: This reduces the number of available databases for the odoo instance to "1", i.e. the named database. In that case, Odoo http handlers always know, which database to use (since there is only one).  The 404 in your question comes because there seem to be multiple databases and Odoo cannot decide against which to authenticate.